# How to use a local version of pm2 in node_modules directory to keep a server alive?

Tags: node.js, express, server, pm2

I want to keep my node server alive. Therefore I use pm2 but if I try to start my server with

> pm2 start index.js

I get the message:

> pm2: command not found

So, I wanted to ask how to use local pm2 in `node_modules` directory without installing pm2 globally.
Do I have to register pm2 in my `index.js`?

Can anyone provide some information about the command to start a server via pm2 which is locally installed?

Comment: did you read the pm2 cli commands? your missing parameters.

Comment: Yes, I read it but not entirely. There stood to use pm2 start any application. I will read it again but nevertheless could you provide an answer if you know the answer?

Comment: @Talg123 I read a bit and saw that they install it globally. Do I have to install it globally? Can't I use it locally somehow? I would mark your answer if you can help!

Comment: yes, you need to install it globally.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can install it as a local project dependency and then run it directly with the path inside node_modules: `node ./node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start`

That way you can use it in a npm script for example.

I use this for a project that needs to run offline, bundling everything in the CI and running it locally then.

However as of lately I get some problems with the deamon starting under Windows that way. Not yet sure if it is a Windows problem or a problem with starting pm2 this way (as the globally installed version still works properly).

Comment: And how do I stop it?

Answer (score 4):

Try,`npx pm2 start index.js`. Read this article to learn about [npx](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/npm-vs-npx-whats-the-difference/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on AWS EC2 instance you can run the command from this path:
`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\pm2 start C:\project\app.js`
In my case pm2 was installed but the err was pm2 npt found
so i ran pm2 command from that path and i worked

Answer (score 0):

If you use npm, simply write in your `package.json` / "scripts":

```
"pm2": "npx pm2 start index.js -i max"
```

then run the script with `npm run pm2`

it will start your index.js with max available cluster workers